# How to make Open Office Writer correct spelling?

Tags: openoffice

It will not automatically correct spelling. Instead it underlines bad words in red. How do I automatically correct spelling?

Answer (score 1):

**First confirm that AutoCorrect is set to operate while typing.**

- `Format -> AutoCorrect -> While Typing` should be checked.
- `Tools -> AutoCorrect Options...`, `Options` tab, `Use replacement table` should be checked in both the [M] (replace while modifying existing text) and [T] (autoformat/autocorrect while typing) columns.

**Only words in the AutoCorrect replacement table will be changed as one types.**

There are two ways to add words to the replacement table.

1. From the `Tools` menu, select `AutoCorrect...`. On the `Replace` tab, enter a misspelled word into the `Replace` text box, enter the correct spelling in the `With` box, then press the `New` button.
2. When a word is underlined in red, right click on it, and select the correct spelling from the `AutoCorrect` submenu. This will automatically place the misspelling and correct spelling in the AutoCorrect replacement table.

---

This answer is based on OpenOffice 4.1.10 and may or may not apply as given in earlier versions.